# SOAPUI Conditional Goto

Tags: api, soapui

Hi I don't know if this is the correct way the question is asked but I want the Conditional GoTo to go to `GetCustomerAccount` when the value is **BCC**(or when the goTo condition is true) and ends at 'CustomerAccount'. And when the value is not BCC, it will just go straight to 'CustomerAccount'. However, when I add a new SOAP Request, it ends at the latest request. Any idea how to solve this?

**BCC Value:**

goTo condition 
[1st Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUBYr.png)

End Result
[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPDsW.png)

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need that the testStep `'CustomerAccount'` will be the last execution, you have 2 option:

1. `'CustomerAccount'` always will be last.
   [image: 1. <code>'CustomerAccount'</code> always will be last.]
2. You need add new testStep -> Add Step -> Run TestStep. In the new window you need to configuration your testStep `CustomerAccount` that you want to run. After you have to update the testStep Goto with the new activity `Run TestCase`.
   Please see the attachment.
   [image: Details exucution goto]
   [image: Goto condition]

Comment: How do you use the 2nd step?

Comment: you need add new testStep -> Add Step -> Run TestStep. In the new window you need to configuration your testStep `CustomerAccount` that you want to run. it is very simple.